# How to get the landing page URL using Google Analytics _UTM Cookies

Tags: cookies, google-analytics

I need to find the landing page url using google analytics cookies, how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The landing page is not in the GA.js cookies, you will need to set it with your own.

Answer (score 0):

**Vinay**,

if you are using Google Analytics, you can [simply parse the cookie](https://github.com/simonrobson/ga_cookie_parser). See this parses on github for example, that should do the trick.

if you are using Universal Analytics, this information is no longer available as UTM cookies were replaced and [the whole hit collection mechanism is now different](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2790010?hl=en).

Hope this helps.